# MySQL Interface in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web

I was wondering if there is a tool (php code) that I can connect to a MySQL database and once connection is made I could use the web interface to query, add, edit stuff on MySQL database?

Your help is appreciated.

note: i want this embedded within my own website so that users could do this, so not phpmyadmin

Perhaps something similar to: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp

at the bottom of the page the user can type their sql query and the results are displayed in the next page

Comment: Take a look at [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) or [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

Comment: I highly recommend phpMyAdmin, as it is both lightweight, functional, and comes standard with cPanel and most other control panels.

Comment: I have had a look at those, but I wanted to publish this within my own website, so that I could include like a 'comment' box in the website and the user could type sql qeuries and when they press submit the query is displayed at the bottom of the page

Comment: be REALLY careful what queries you allow visitors to run

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Yepp, the site will be protected with a username and password, otherwise they can't access it at all, but Thanks :)

Comment: Yes because password security is enough oO. `DROP DATABASE yourwebsite;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to see your databases

```
$set = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES;');
$dbs = array();
while($db = mysql_fetch_row($set))
   $dbs[] = $db[0];
echo implode('<br/>', $dbs);
```

You can edit specific tables using a CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) script.

http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/12/php-and-mysql-crud-tutorial.html

And show tables using:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Comment: nopp it's a hosted MySQL, my hosting company provides that, but I want an interface WITHIN my own website

Comment: so what PHP code will I need to put into my 'index.php' to put a comment box where the user can type the sql query and it displays the results below?

Comment: editted my answer. hope it's what you mean.

Comment: yepp this is very close to what I want....just trying to figure out the code or shall I say simplify it to understand it better

Comment: glad i know what u mean. remember. if it's useful accept :)

Comment: if you have global questions about it i'll help you with that :)

Comment: Thanks....off course, that's the least I could do ;-)

Comment: You can upvote answers on this page by clicking the arrow up. or you can downvote answers by obviously the arrow down. accepting works for 1 answer only. you can click the checkmark to accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Luckily for you, yes there are multiple!

**phpMyAdmin (most popular):** http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

**Chive:** http://www.chive-project.com/

**SQL Buddy:** http://sqlbuddy.com/

Personally I use PHPMyAdmin.

Concerning embedding it in your own website, you could probably alter any of the above to function in this way; you could even do it using iframes (although that probably wouldn't be the prettiest solution). You'd have to make sure the authors allow you to edit their software in this way before doing so however.

The alternative is to try making your own database viewer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use phpmyadmin or any other existing web based sql database manager then you'll have to scratch write your own. Including display based off variable size database tables and columns etc. Input and output validation and security.

Rule of thumb never ever ever let users query your database directly no matter what security you have in place as you'll always have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You need `PhpMyAdmin` for this. Download `PhpMyAdmin` from below link :

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Comment: He specifically said no PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Jueecy  After we all gave this answer then he updated the question with that note.

Comment: Edited my question: Perhaps something similar to: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp

at the bottom of the page the user can type their sql query and the results are displayed in the next page

Comment: You better update your answer or delete it.

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, forgive me for being a newbee :(

Comment: Well i am searching for another answer but it is not the right thing to downvote it.

Comment: Look he is accepting his mistake

Comment: @DeadMan, it is. You update your answer and you let me know and I'll uncast my down vote.

Comment: @Jueecy ok, i will try to find the right answer or i will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting tool, which allows for you to do all the things you listed (and much more).